# Help with under the sink filter installation

Tags: plumbing, sink

I have an old Omnifilter SMF2 under the sink water filter that I am needing to connect. The people who redid my kitchen plumbing installed a dedicated 1/2" cold water supply line and I need it to connect to the filter cartridge housing. The problem is that all of the new fittings that I ordered are all quick connects for a 3/8" pvc tubing ([I have this John Guest faucet connector](https://www.h2odistributors.com/ci3212u7s)). What part do I need to connect a 1/2" thread male cold water supply to a quick connect housing that takes 3/8" tubing ([this is the part that is currently on the filter cartridge housing](https://www.homedepot.com/p/John-Guest-3-8-in-Push-To-Connect-x-3-8-in-MIP-Polypropylene-Adapter-Fitting-803239/300753462))

I've attached a photo of the dedicated water line that has the 1/2" threaded male part. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would not go with the PVC tubing and push to connect fittings.

You can **replace the fitting in the filter housing** with one that will except a standard [faucet supply line](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Homewerks-Worldwide-3-8-in-Compression-30-in-Braided-Stainless-Steel-Faucet-Supply-Line/1000011700) with 1/2" fitting in its end. The filter is under the sink so a faucet supply line should be long enough (*they come in several lengths*)  the other end of the supply line is a 3/8" and will fit right on your current shut off valve.

Find the supply line in the store and tell the associate that you need to replace the fitting in your filter housing to one that will accept the 1/2 inch. IPS end of the supply line.

Only two parts needed, the new filter fitting and the faucet supply line (*and some teflon tape for installing the new filter fitting into the filter housing. You do not need the teflon tape on the fitting threads that except the supply line as they are compression and have rubber gaskets pre-installed.*)

Comment: This sounds like a good plan to me the push connectors are ok but the tubing gets kinked easily the pre made ones are similar but usually have a protective braid. They are usually oring sealed so don’t over tighten.